# Android WebView Screen freezes on tapping non clickable areas

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a few buttons on my webView and I want only them to be clickable.

At present if I click on free space or text area, the graphics become distorted and soon the whole thing freezes.

I tried to override the OnTouchListener using

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This serves my purpose partially. Now the screen doesn get selected on tap but even the button are not clickable any more.

Comment: Could you check LogCat for messages.

Comment: Getting 2 warnings...

1) No keyboard for id 0

2) 08-21 16:58:07.070: W/KeyCharacterMap(6960): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

Answer (score 0):

check your logcat. there might be any exception occurring which you are not able to catch. find that exception.

Comment: Getting 2 warnings...

1) No keyboard for id 0

2) 08-21 16:58:07.070: W/KeyCharacterMap(6960): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

Comment: Can i check the event triggering the touch in the above code itself and accordingly return a true or false ??